# Merging records in a table and update related tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a main table containing users that are linked to various other tables.  Sometimes there are duplicates in this main table due to bad imported data and I would like to merge them.  See the following tables.

Table:  Users

```
UserID    Username    FirstName    LastName
1         Main        John         Doe
2         Duplicate   John         Doo
```

Table: Records1

```
RecordID  RecordName      CreatedUserID   UpdatedUserID
1         Test record 1   1               2
2         Test record 2   2               null
3         Test record 3   2               null
```

CreatedUserID and UpdatedUserID are foreign columns of Users.UserID.
So currently if I want to merge user 1 and 2, I would do it with these SQL statements:

```
UPDATE Records1 SET UpdatedUserID = 1 WHERE UpdatedUserID = 2
UPDATE Records1 SET CreatedUserID = 1 WHERE CreatedUserID = 2
DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserID = 2
```

This is just a sample subset but in reality, there are a LOT of related records tables for which I have to add additional SQL-Update statements.

I know I'm probably pushing my luck here, but is there perhaps a way to accomplish the above (update all related tables in a batch and delete the "duplicate" record) rather than updating each foreign field and each related table manually.  The users table is basically the base table that links to all other tables so to create individual statements for each table is rather cumbersome so if a shortcut is available, that would be great.

Comment: There is no shortcut here. When you need to update a bunch of data in a bunch of tables you have to update each table individually. This sounds like a great time for a stored procedure. Write it once and receive two parameters (new and old). Then start writing updates.

Comment: Well I supposed you could probably write some REALLY ugly dynamic sql to search for columns in all tables with certain names. Then write up some dynamic sql to update the table based on the new and old values. But honestly that might actually as much time, or even more, than writing out the updates.

Comment: Not clear to me.

Comment: Break it down into steps _thinking in sets_: (1) Generate pairs of `UserId` values with a _keeper_ and a _victim_ and save them in a table. (One query ought to be able to generate all of the pairs if you can define suitable rules for "duplicates".) (B) One query per related table to update all of the _victim_ values to the corresponding _keeper_ values. (You can update multiple columns in one pass, but it can get ugly.) (iii) One query to houseclean the _victims_ from the `Users` table. (four) Delete the table of pairs.

Comment: You don't need to write individual `UPDATE` queries for every `UserID` use @HABO method to do it in batches.

Comment: how did you decided 2 is duplicate of 1.? What is the criteria to decide a record is duplicate of another.? based on first name.?

Comment: @Sahi It is manual.  The user selects two or more records in the program and clicks the Merge button and specify which record should remain.

Comment: @SeanLange That's what I figured.  I thought maybe there is some built-in SQL functionality that I don't know about that would do something like this.

Comment: @HABO If I understand your solution correctly, I think this is what I'm doing at the moment.  I basically have a merging table that contains the names of all the fields in related tables that needs to be updated or deleted if a record gets merged in the main table.  I then run through that table and generate a SQL update statement for each row, but it obviously require that the table be maintained.  I guess I'll continue with this path then.

Answer (score 0):

is this helpful.?

```
    Create Table Users(Id int, UserName varchar(10),FirstName varchar(10), LastName Varchar(10))
    Create Table Records1(RecordID int,  RecordName varchar(20), CreatedUserID int,   UpdatedUserID int)


    INSERT INTO Users
    SELECT 1,'Main','John','Doe' Union All
    SELECT 2,'Duplicate','John','Doo' Union All

    SELECT 3,'Main3','ABC','MPN' Union All
    SELECT 4,'Duplicate','ABC','MPT' 


    Insert into Records1
    SELECT 1,'Test record 1',1,2    Union All
    SELECT 2,'Test record 2',2,null Union All
    SELECT 3,'Test record 3',2,null Union All

    SELECT 1,'Test record 1',3,4    Union All
    SELECT 2,'Test record 2',4,null Union All
    SELECT 3,'Test record 3',4,null 

    Select u1.Id as CreatedUserID,U2.id as UpdatedUserID
    Into #tmpUsers 
    from Users u1
    JOIN Users u2 
    --This Conidition Should be changed based on the criteria for identifying Duplicates
    on u1.FirstName=u2.FirstName and U2.UserName='Duplicate'
    Where u1.UserName<>'Duplicate'


    Update r
    Set r.UpdatedUserID=u.CreatedUserID
    From Records1 r
    JOIN #tmpUsers u on r.CreatedUserID=u.CreatedUserID

    Update r
    Set r.CreatedUserID=u.CreatedUserID
    From Records1 r
    JOIN #tmpUsers u on r.CreatedUserID=u.UpdatedUserID

    Delete from Users Where UserName='Duplicate'

    Select * from Users
    Select * from Records1


    Drop Table #tmpUsers
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the process of identifying duplicate accounts will be manual then there will (generally) be pairs of accounts to be processed. (I'm assuming that the Inspector can't tick off 15 user accounts as duplicates in your UI and submit the whole lot for processsing.)

A stored procedure like the following may be a good start:

```
create procedure MergeUsers
  @RetainedUserId Int, -- UserId   that is being kept.
  @VictimUserId Int -- UserId   that is to be removed.

as
  begin

  -- Validate the input.
  --   Optional, but you may want some reality checks.
  --   (Usernames are probably unique already, eh?)
  declare @UsernameMatch as Int, @FirstNameMatch as Int, @LastNameMatch as Int, @EmailMatch as Int;
  select
    @UsernameMatch = case when R.Username = V.Username then 1 else 0 end,
    @FirstNameMatch = case when R.FirstName = V.FirstName then 1 else 0 end,
    @LastNameMatch = case when R.LastName = V.LastName then 1 else 0 end,
    @EmailMatch = case when R.Email= V.Emailthen 1 else 0 end
    from Users as R inner join
      Users as V on V.UserId = @VictimUserId and R.UserId = @RetainedUserId;
  if @UsernameMatch + @FirstNameMatch + @LastNameMatch + @EmailMatch < 2
    begin
    -- The following message should be enhanced to provide a better clue as to which user
    --   accounts are being processed and what did or didn't match.
    RaIsError( 'MergeUsers: The two user accounts should have something in common.', 25, 42 );
    return;
    end;

  -- Update all of the related tables.
  --   Using a single pass through each table and updating all of the appropriate columns may improve performance.
  --   The   case   expression will only alter the values which reference the victim user account.
  update Records1
    set
      CreatedUserId = case when CreatedUserId  = @VictimId then @RetainedUserId else CreatedUserId end,
      UpdatedUserId = case when UpdatedUserId = @VictimId then @RetainedUserId else UpdatedUserId end
    where CreatedUserId = @VictimUserId or UpdatedUserId = @VictimUserId;

  update Records2
    set ...
    where ...;

  -- Houseclean   Users .
  delete from Users
    where UserId = @VictimUserId;

  end;
```

**NB**: Left as an exercise is adding `try`/`catch` and a transaction in the SP to ensure that the merge is an all or nothing operation.